# Variables in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a general question related to MS SQL Server.

I want to use a variable internal to my stored procedure. All the variables I declare allow for user input. Is there a way to create a variable that is not exposed to a 'User'? I know I can make a variable optional.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far. It is possible.

Comment: Of course. Variables by definition are not accessible outside the procedure. Don't confuse parameters with variables. Syntactically they look the same but they are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just declare the variable inside the body of the procedure, not as an input parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProc
   --these are input parameters which the user/caller can specify values for
   @parameter1 nvarchar(50),
   @parameter2 int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @parameter3 int; -- this is a variable which is private to the procedure.

   SET @parameter3 = 7; -- this sets the value of the variable. Of course you could set its value another way by taking it from a table, or doing a calculation, whatever you need.

   SELECT somefield FROM sometable WHERE anotherfield = @parameter3;
END
```

You may also want to [review the relevant T-SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) about this topic